# How to get one field value in Mongodb collection

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, pymongo, pymongo-3.x

I want get all dates in mycollection in **MongoDb**

**Database Name** is : mydb

**Collection Name**: mycollection

Document1:

```
"Date":"10-01-2020", "timeslot1":"11-12" ,"timeslot2":null ,"timeslot3":null ,"timeslot4":null
```

Document2:

```
 "Date":"11-01-2020", "timeslot1":null ,"timeslot2":null ,"timeslot3":null ,"timeslot4":null
```

Document3:

```
 "Date":"14-01-2020", "timeslot1":null ,"timeslot2":null ,"timeslot3":null ,"timeslot4":null
```

I want All dates.I want output like this

```
{10-01-2020, 11-01-2020, 14-01-2020}
```

I am trying this query:

```
x = mydb.mycollection.find({}, {"Date": 1})
  print(x)
```

I get Output like this

```
<pymongo.cursor.Cursor object at 0x000002120610EF98>
```

Comment: x = mydb.mycollection.distinct("Date")
use like this

Comment: Thank you vicky. But that logic is getting an empty list[ ]

Comment: empty array means there is no datas!!!!!!

Comment: is there data means
output will be [
10-01-2020, 11-01-2020, 14-01-2020
]

Answer (score 0):

Basically `.find()` would return a cursor - which is why your output of `print(x)` is `<pymongo.cursor.Cursor object at 0x000002120610EF98>`, You need to iterate through to access documents out of it, Also I've added `_id:0` in projection in order to explicitly exclude `_id` field, which is by default included. This for loop will print values of x until cursor is exhausted, Try this :

```
for x in mydb.mycollection.find({}, {_id :0, "Date": 1}):
  print(x)
```

In case if you need distinct date values :

```
for x in mydb.mycollection.distinct('Date'):
    print(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `list` to convert your cursor to list.

```
x = mydb.mycollection.find({}, {"Date": 1})
y = list(x)

print(y)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mydb.mycollection.find({}, {"Date": 1})
```

and if you want from multiple tables then you should use aggregate funcationaity

Comment: That's exactly what OP is doing & has already mentioned in question, unfortunately this doesn't need to be an answer, the issue is completely different, he wants it's to be accessed or printed :-) !!

Answer (score 0):

```
my_cursor = mydb.mycollection.find()
for x in my_cursor:
    print('{0}'.format(x['Date']))
```

Comment: See "[Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/128421)". While this might be technically correct it doesn't explain why it solves the problem or should be the selected answer. We should educate in addition to help solve the problem.